# Understanding UDP networking on python example

Tags: udp

I have UDP client:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread


def wait_response(s):
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        if data:
            data = data.decode('utf-8')
            print("Received from server: " + data)




def main():
    host = ''
    port = 5000
    server = ('-.-.-.-', 8888)

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    d = Thread(target=wait_response, args=(s,))
    d.setDaemon(True)
    d.start()

    message = raw_input("\n->")

    while message != 'q':
        s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server)
        message = raw_input("->")
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

And I have UDP server:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread


def wait_response(s, c_a):
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        if data:
            c_a.addr = addr
            data = data.decode('utf-8')
            print("Recived from client: " + data)


class Upd_client_address_container(object):
    addr = ''


def main():
    host = "---.---.---.---" # my ip here
    port = 8888

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    connection_addr = Upd_client_address_container()

    d = Thread(target=wait_response, args=(s, connection_addr,))
    d.deamon = True
    d.start()

    print("Server started")
    message = 'Connection with server established'
    while message != 'q':
        if connection_addr.addr:
            s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), connection_addr.addr)
            message = raw_input("->")
    s.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tested it inside corporate network and it works fine. But when I send `client` part outside the local network we have failed to establish connection. Which steps should be done to fix this problem?

Comment: You don't need to fix your code, you need to fix your network. Either your server is behind a NAT gateway, and you need to configure port forwarding on your router towards your server application and your client needs to use the public IP address to connect to your server. And/or there's a firewall somewhere inbetween that stops your packets.

Comment: @nos, can I bind to socket not only `ip` but whole `traceroute` or it doesn't make sense?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say.